# Dropdown menu not working in IE9 and 10 when click on drop down menu icon

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

Kindly Help, my search drop down are not working  in Internet Explorer 10 and 9 when click on drop down arrow icons.  Working good with internet explorer 11 edge, google crome and mozilla forefox.

Although drop down menus are working in all browsers when click on Text (SysRef wriiten in select box) .

Please watch snapshot for better understanding :
[image]

Doc tag used is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<![endif]-->
```

HTML COde is :

```html
<div class="search">
 <span class="search-btn">
  <span class="open">
   <i class="ico ico-zoom"></i>
   Search
  </span>
 
  <span class="close hidden">
   <i class="ico ico-x"></i>
   Close
  </span>
 </span>
 
 <div class="form-body hidden">
 
 <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-select" class="form-label">Select Column</label>     
     <div class="form-controls">
      <label class="select-label">
       <select id="colList1" name="colList1" class="select">
        <c:forEach var="column" items="${colList1}">
         <option value="${column}" <c:if test="${column == colListSelection1}">SELECTED</c:if>>${column}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>            
      </label>
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->       
          
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-criteria" class="form-label">Search Criteria</label>     
     <div class="form-controls">      
      <input type="text" class="field" name="value1" id="value1" value="${value1}" onKeyPress="javascript:validateEnterKeyOnSearch(event,this.form,this)">      
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->
          
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-criteria" class="form-label">&nbsp;</label>
     <div class="form-controls">
      <label class="select-label">      
       <select name="andOr" id="andOr" class="select select-small">
        <option value="and" <c:if test="${andOr == 'and'}">SELECTED</c:if>>and</option>
        <option value="or" <c:if test="${andOr == 'or'}">SELECTED</c:if>>or</option>
       </select>       
      </label>
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->
          
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-column2" class="form-label">Select Column</label>
     
     <div class="form-controls">
      <label class="select-label">
       <select name="colList2" id="colList2" class="select">
        <c:forEach var="column" items="${colList2}">
         <option value="${column}" <c:if test="${column == colListSelection2}">SELECTED</c:if>>${column}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>
      </label>
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->
          
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-criteria2" class="form-label">Search Criteria</label>
     
     <div class="form-controls">
      <input type="text" class="field" name="value2" id="value2" value="${value2}" onKeyPress="javascript:validateEnterKeyOnSearch(event, this.form, this)">           
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->
          
    <div class="form-actions">    
     <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="javascript:performSearch(this.form.name,<%=AppProperties.ROWS_PER_PAGE%>,<%=AppProperties.ELCY_LIST_MAX_SIZE%>);" class="btn btn-green" />
    </div><!-- /.form-actions -->
 
 </div> <!-- /.Form-body -->
 
</div><!-- /.search -->
<input type="hidden" name="submitSearch" id="submitSearch" value="true"/>
```

CSS code Used is :

```css
/* ==========================================================================
 #Search
========================================================================== */
.search { float: left; margin-left: 4px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; font-family: "Arial Black","Arial Bold",Gadget,sans-serif; }
.search-btn { display: inline-block; width: 90px; height: 28px; margin: 21px 0 0 4px; background-color: #55be28; font-size: 11px; line-height: 28px; text-align: center; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer; }
.search-btn { 
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
         transition: opacity 0.4s;
 }
.search-btn:hover { opacity: .7; }
.search-btn .ico { margin-right: 5px; }

.form-body,
.form-row { display: inline-block; }

.form-body.hidden { opacity: 0; }
.form-body { opacity: 1; }
.form-body { 
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
      -o-transition: opacity 1s;
         transition: opacity 1s;
 }

.form-row { margin-left: 10px;}
.form-label { display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 7px; font-size: 10px; line-height: 13px; color: #464646; }
.field,
.select { width: 88px; height: 28px; padding: 0 10px; border: 1px solid  #e1e1e1; font-size: 11px; line-height: 28px; color: #464646; }
.field-small { width: 65px; }

.select { width: 110px; height: 30px; }
.select-small { width: 70px; }/*48px original*/

.form-controls label + input { margin-left: 20px; } 
.form-controls label .ico { margin: -17px 0 0 5px; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer; }
.form-controls label { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
.form-controls .select-label:after { content: ''; position: absolute; top: 1px; right: 1px; width: 29px; height: 28px; background: url(images/sprite.png) -124px -27px no-repeat; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: none; }

.form-actions { overflow: hidden; /*padding-top: 5px; by me*/  display: inline; }
.form-actions .btn { float: right; /*Extra from me*/ margin:21px 0 0 10px; }
.hidden { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You should take all of that code and make [an example of the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you are experiencing.

Comment: I am saying, My select box is not opening while clicking on arrow icon  in Internet Explorer 9 and 10. Required code is provided above.

Comment: Right, but what I am saying is that rather than making the people who are going to help *you* put all of the code into verifiable code editor, like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), you should create a [minimal, verifiable example, yourself,  displaying the issue you are experiencing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will not only improve the question but increase the likelihood you that you will get a useful answer.